# Using Outlook controls in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

**Objective**: When compared, I feel the looks of outlook control is better than the ordinary. So what I want to do is use the outlook controls like buttons, textbox instead of the ordinary one (builtin controls).

**Problem**: When I place the control on the VBE Userform, I get the `System Error H80004005 (-2147467259). Unspecified error`

[image]

**Question**: Is it possible to use ms outlook controls in excel vba?

These are the highlighted controls that I would like to use.

[image]

Comment: Then what you want to do with outlook control. Send mail?

Comment: i like the the ui of the textbox, buttons, checkbox control and etc. so do you think sending mail is my purpose?

Comment: @SiddharthRout thank you for the question. compare the looks of outlook control is better than the ordinary. so what i want to do is use the outlook controls like buttons, textbox instead of the ordinary one(builtin controls)

Comment: If I am not wrong, you can add most of these controls to a form region in outlook form using the forms designer. You cannot add these controls to a VB UserForm object in the VBE. What you are asking is really a good question. It is just that you need to mention in your question what exactly you are trying to achieve else it may get downvoted and closed... I would recommend updating your question.

Comment: And yes... you should avoid using additional controls if you are planning to distribute your workbook because the other person may not have those controls(ocs, tlb, dll etc files). For example Lot of people use MS office wihout having Outlook installed ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout i apologized for my post and thank you so much for your time. actually i already tried using the controls in vba excel and not in outlook itself and upon inserting the controls, nothing shows in the form and at the same time it gives a prompt System Error H80004005 (-2147467259). Unspecified error. thats why i post my question here if it is possible to use the outlook controls in vba excel and hoping that some will give me a good answer not a stupid question right?. anyways, again thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Yes you will not be able to use them on VBE Userforms. No question is stupid. As per me, there are 2 types of questions (You may disagree). *Good questions and Vague questions*. Unfortunately, your question in the current format falls under "Vague questions" and hence I guess it is being downvoted and may get closed soon. Like I mentioned above, update your question. Explain exactly what you are trying to achieve and what problems are you currently facing (For example that error message) ;)

Comment: See I updated your question. Now tell me... Does it make more sense to readers as to what you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: thank you again for explaining that to me well... :) hope i can give you extra credit for that :)

Comment: yes you are right.. it makes more sense toe the reader... again i apologize for my action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not wrong, unfortunately, you cannot add these controls to a VB UserForm object in the VBE.

You can only add these controls to a form region in outlook form using the forms designer.

Having said that, you should avoid using additional controls if you are planning to distribute your workbook because the other person may not have those controls installed. For example, lot of people use MS office without having MS Outlook installed.

Comment: noted on this. thank you once again for the help